# I want to calculate the average of the 6 months prior to the given month in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, average

[image: imgur]

sample code:

```
SELECT Avg(dt.number_of_employees)
FROM   (SELECT number_of_employees
        FROM   my_table
        ORDER  BY date DESC
        LIMIT  1, 6) dt;
```

but did not work. How can I calculate with php?

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and don't just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PHP to calculate, MySQL will do it just fine:

```sql
SELECT emp.date, emp.number_of_employees, six_mo_avg.avg_emp, ROUND(six_mo_avg.avg_emp) avg_emp_rounded
    FROM my_table emp
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT e.date,
            (SELECT avg(avgemp.number_of_employees) avg_emp
            FROM my_table avgemp
            WHERE avgemp.date BETWEEN e.date - INTERVAL 6 MONTH AND e.date
            GROUP BY 1=1) avg_emp
        FROM my_table e) six_mo_avg ON six_mo_avg.date = emp.date
ORDER BY emp.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is works as shown in this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b17749/1.

```
set @rownum := 0;
set @rownum2 := 0;
set @lastrownum := (select count(*) from my_table); 
select date,
       number_of_employees,
       sum(number_of_employees)/(maxrownum-rnum+1) as avg_per_6months,
       round(sum(number_of_employees)/(maxrownum-rnum+1),0) as avg_rounded
from (
 select t.date, 
     t.number_of_employees,
      s.rnum,
      s.maxrownum,
      t.rnum2
   from (
select date,   
(@rownum := @rownum + 1) as rnum,
(case when @lastrownum <= @rownum + 5  then @lastrownum 
      else (@rownum + 5) end) as maxrownum
from my_table
order by date desc) s
cross join (
select date, number_of_employees, 
(@rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1) as rnum2 
from my_table
order by date desc) t ) v 
where rnum2 between rnum and maxrownum
group by rnum
order by rnum, rnum2
```